# Is there any better way to get sum number of reactions

Tags: openfda

I used this api call to get expected number of reactions:
https://api.fda.gov/drug/event?&search=???&count=patient.reaction.reactionmeddrapt.exact&limit=24

But as I only get part of the data, I don't have the sum number to calculate rates for each reaction. But fetching all reactions takes too much time. Is there any better way to get the number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `limit`, use date boundaries instead:

https://api.fda.gov/drug/event?&search=penicilin+AND+[2004-12-31+TO+2005-01-01]&count=patient.reaction.reactionmeddrapt.exact

https://open.fda.gov/api/reference/#dates-and-ranges